# "No time" meaning

Tags: meaning, idioms

Good day all.
I would like to know what exactly Cecile McLorin Salvant has in mind when saying "no time" in the song called "Nobody"? Does it mean "never"?

"Nobody, I will never do nothing for nobody, no time!" ([this song on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kxDdkphgwQ)).

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. The full expression is a prepositional phrase, 'at no time'.: _at no time_
never _At no time did I ever say or suggest or even hint that she should lie about what I was doing._ {[Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms ](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+no+time)} Here, double negatives don't seem to worry the writer/s.

Comment: "Not at any time" (in the future).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"No time" in this case is an informal double negative, such as is common in many informal American dialects, including many African-American dialects.

In learning formal English, you will learn that a single negative negates the sentence, and a double negative negates the negation, so that:

> "I know nothing about birthing babies"

means you are ignorant, while

> "There is nothing I don't know about birthing babies"

means you are competent. However, in informal speech, additional negatives can also be used to reinforce a negative meaning, so that:

> "I don't know nothing about birthing no babies"

means you are completely ignorant of the birthing process.

The negatives in the passage you quote serve this purpose: reinforcing the overall negative aspect of the sentiment. If you were to rephrase it in a more formal American register, it might read like this:

> I will not, at any time, do anything for anybody.